# javascript onclick toggle style display

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have a 'toggle display' between 'none' and 'block' on two elements on my webpage using javascript and an html link. There should be two DIVs on the page, when one is display: block, the other is display: none, with a link to toggle each div.

my html:

```
<div class="uvp_bar_display" id="uvp_bar">
<a class="" href="#document_body" id="uvp_bar_link" onclick="uvp_toggle_display(['uvp_bar_display', 'uvp_display'])"><img alt="" height="40" id="uvp_bar_image" src="/asset/image/sea_foam_minimized.gif" width="960px" /></a>
</div>

<div class="uvp_display" id="uvp">
<img alt="sea foam" height="400" id="uvp_image" onclick="uvp_toggle_display(['uvp_bar_display', 'uvp_display'])" src="/asset/image/image.jpg" width="960" />
</div>
```

my javascript:

```
function uvp_toggle_display($ids) { 
   $id = Araray.isArray($ids) ? $ids : [$ids]; 
   $id.forEach(function $i) { 
      document.getElementById = 
        (document.getElementById($i).style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none'; 
   }
}
```

I'm not looking for a jquery solution,

thanks

Comment: I admin I'm a noob to javascript, but I only have so much patience, this is my updated foreach statement: updated:     function uvp_toggle_display($ids) {
     $id = Araray.isArray($ids) ? $ids : [$ids];
  $id.forEach(function $i) {
      document.getElementById = (document.getElementById($i).style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
     }
    }

Comment: I'm re-assigning the value of document.getElementById because that is the purpose of the script, the link changes display: none to display: block and display block to display: none;

Answer (score 1):

**You have several syntax errors in your code and the structure of your HTML will make the link that toggles the display disappear after the first click.**

**You don't modify the value of `document.getElementById` to show or hide something in the DOM.** [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is a built-in function that scans the document and returns to you a refrence to the object who's `id` you've specified. If you set that equal (`=`) to something, you wipe out its built in functionality.

**You need to access the `display` property of the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) object of the DOM element and the [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) values to get and set CSS styles.**

Also, **don't use inline HTML event handling attributes** (`onclick`, etc.) as they create "spaghetti code", create anonymous global functions that modify the `this` binding and don't follow the **[W3C DOM Event Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events)**

See this for the correct solution and explanations via the comments:

```js
// First, wait until the DOM is loaded and then begin:
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 
  // Get a reference to the link:
  var link = document.getElementById("uvp_bar_link");
  
  // Get references to the divs that need to be shown/hidden
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll("#uvp_bar, #uvp");
  
  // Set up a click event handler for the link:
  link.addEventListener("click", uvp_toggle_display);
  
  
  // This is the function that will run when the link has been clicked
  function uvp_toggle_display(evt){
    // First, prevent the native behavior of the link:
    evt.preventDefault();
    
    // And, cancel the event from bubbling to other elements
    evt.stopPropagation();
    
    // Now, toggle the divs by looping through the group
    divs.forEach(function(div){

      // And change the display based on what it is now.
      // NOTE: inline styles are gotten and set via: element.style
      //       but styles set anywhere else are gotten from window.getComputedStyle(element)
      div.style.display = (window.getComputedStyle(div).display === "none") ? "block" : "none";
    });
      
  }
  
});
```

```css
/* Don't set style information in HTML attributes, that's what CSS is for
   See how much cleaner your HTML is now?                                   */
#uvp_bar_image {width:960px; height:40px; }
#uvp_image { width:960px; height:400px;}

/* Start the page off with one div not shown: */
#uvp { display:none;}
```

```html
<!-- Your HTML was not correct for a few reasons:
    1. You had inline event handlers (onclick)
    2. You had attributes with no values (alt="", class="")
    3. You were setting style information (height and width) using HTML attributes
       3a. That should be done with CSS
       3b. Even if you were going to do it in HTML, you included "px" in the values which is wrong
    4. You can't have the link that toggles the visibility of the divs in one of the divs that 
       will wind up being hidden because you'll hide the link that brings it back.
-->

<div>
    <a href="#document_body" id="uvp_bar_link">Toggle divs</a>
</div>

<div class="uvp_bar_display" id="uvp_bar">
    <img id="uvp_bar_image" src="/asset/image/sea_foam_minimized.gif" alt="image 1">
</div>

<div class="uvp_display" id="uvp">
  <img alt="sea foam" id="uvp_image" src="/asset/image/image.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is simple toggle between two div, use this:

```
<div>
    <div id="div1" style="display:block;">
        <h1>Displaying Div 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="div2"  style="display:none;">
       <h1>Displaying Div 2</h1>
     </div>
   <button type="submit" id="btnTogle">Togle</button>
 </div>

<script>
var button = document.getElementById('btnTogle');
button.onclick = function () {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

    if (div1.style.display === 'none') {
        div1.style.display = 'block';
        div2.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        div1.style.display = 'none';
        div2.style.display = 'block';
    }
 };
</script>
```

Comment: thats good, but I need the link to work without a button, just a link like <div><a href="#whateverhere" id="image_uvp"><img ...</ img></div><div><a href=""#whathereever" id="image_at"><img ....</img></div>

Comment: following sanjeev bhusals example that would be

var image_at = document.getElementById('image_at');
image_at.onclick = function(.....

beware that a link has a default action, leading to #whathereever.

think of using a background-image for the button, that can solve this conflict

Comment: This will fail if you follow best practices and not use inline styles unless absolutely necessary.